# What are the keyboard shortcuts to operate a Mac slider control

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, safari

In the Safari RSS screen, there is a slider (or range) control to change an article's summary length. By pressing TAB a couple of times, it is possible to navigate to this control, without using the mouse.

Is it also possible, to slide the slider with the keyboard? Thus sliding the knob to the right and left? The volume slider in iTunes can be operated by the arrow-keys, but in Safari's RSS window, these are used to scroll the text if there are any scrollbars...

*Note: in System Preferences, Keyboard (OS X 10.6), Keyboard Shortcuts, I have set Full Keyboard Access to All controls. Otherwise, the TAB key only navigates between text boxes and lists.*

Comment: Actually, without that system preference, Option-Tab would still get you to *any* control, including that slider. I can't get it to move using the keyboard though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Web Inspector (or simply view source) reveals:

```
<input id="apple-rss-slider" type="range" min="0" value="29" max="100"
  onmousedown="startScale()" onmouseup="endScale()" 
  oninput="scaleArticles(this.value)" />
```

The `oninput` made me hope I could start typing, but it seems it's all mouse events...

Some HTML5 [examples](http://www.w3.org/2007/03/XForms-Transitional/5/Overview.html) explain how to add additional spin buttons, which can be selected using Option-Tab, followed by Return to press it:

[image: Input type="range" in Safari]

But lack of keyboard support seems an old WebKit bug: [input type range broken for keyboard users](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14444).

The above example looks different in Firefox, and allows for typing a value:

[image: Input type="range" in Firefox]

Comment: I was looking for native keyboard shortcuts, but no go. Thanks for the reference to the webkit bug.

Comment: I guess that one could add some `onkeypress` to the HTML of the RSS view (automated using some Greasemonkey script, http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/11/14/how-to-run-greasemonkey-scripts-in-safari/), if that would help... Seems a bit over the top though?